# Can't dismiss the dialog in my Android app

Tags: android, dialog, webview, dismiss

I have some code here (my activity class and some class, that extends WebViewClient)
so, in my activity I do something like this:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch(id) {
        case 1:
            //logging vk dialog
            Log.d("OLOLOLO", "webview"); 
            dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.webviewl);
            dialog.setTitle("loggin in");

            webview = (WebView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.vkWebView);
            webview.setWebViewClient(wvClforVK);  
            webview.loadUrl(url);
            // do the work to define the pause Dialog 
            break;
        case 2:
            // already logged vk dialog
            break;
        default:
            dialog = null;
    }
    return dialog;
}
```

and then call `showDialog(1)` on some `buttonclick` listener.

In my webview class in `onPageFinished()` method I need to dismiss my dialog but I think it will be incorrect to do this:

```
MyActivity activity = new MyActivity();  //my main activity object
activity.dismissDialog(1);
```

It doesn't work:

> 01-03 20:41:10.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1172): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no dialog with id 1 was ever shown via Activity#showDialog

How can I get my activity object to **correctly** dismiss the dialog?

Comment: I'm glad to see I am not the only one who spams the log with things like 'OLOLOLO'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you instantiate a new activity which doesn't have any dialog. You have to call the dismissDialog method on the same activity instance in which you created the dialog. If you call it in another class, you have to pass your activity somehow to that class (for example you can pass it as a parameter). Anyway, it is not recommended to instantiate activities in this way, they are instantiated automatically if you defined them in the manifest file of your project.

Comment: so tell me please, how can i destroy my dialog when the page in webview have already loaded?

Comment: Please send me the whole class of your activity. I want to see your onPageFinished method.

Comment: You have to write something like this: webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

   @Override
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {   
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    YourActivity.this.dismissDialog(YOUR_DIALOG_ID);
   }
   
  });

Comment: i have 2 classes...first - my activity, second - webview client with onPageFinished() method. so, in my activity i create dialog,webview with the client and put it to dialog( by dialog.setContentView), and need to diamiss it in onPageFinished() method.  YourActivity.this.dismissDialog doesnt work, "No enclosing instance blabla" ((

Comment: In the constructor of your webview client class you can pass a parameter with your activity. Then you save this activity in a field and call the dismiss method on that field. If it is not clear send me the two classes and I can give you the solution more exactly.

Comment: I modified your classes, I couldn't verify because I don't have your whole project, but it should work. Please download the modified classes from here: webView.java - https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B-l_V-7SKTzYN2RiOTE3NzEtNDc2YS00ZDU0LTk4NGEtZmZlNTg0YjNkZDNj&hl=en_US      activity.java - https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B-l_V-7SKTzYNmRkMjZlY2QtZWE1ZC00YjI4LWI0ZTAtNTdjNGRiMTc1M2Iw&hl=en_US    I hope that they work.

Comment: Sorry, the page (or document) you have requested is not available.
Please check the address and try again.  cant access the document((

Comment: Try this links: http://www.2shared.com/file/5rc7x4Mf/activity.html
http://www.2shared.com/file/lKrFm8_c/webview.html

Answer (score 1):

As the exception says, you are trying to dismiss a dialog that was not shown before using showDialog. You need to check the life cycle of the dialog. You can use `Dialog.isShowing()` method to confirm the dialog is shown before dismissing it.

Comment: i did it, and i know, that my dialog shown before dismissing..the problem in activity object...i cant get it correclty

Comment: Is MyActivity a new Activity? If you are in the same activity you run showDialog dismissDialog(1) will sufice (you don't need activity.dismissDialog(1)). If not use context=dialog.getContext() and then context.dismiss dialog(1)

Comment: i tried it...but it is no dismissDialog() method in Context object